# duplicate mvc model property on two jquery ui tabs

Tags: jquery

I am new to MVC and I am using jQuery tabs in an MVC4 project.
I want to have a duplicate bound property display on two tabs.
What is the best way to handle this so the property can be updated from either tab?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up placing the duplicate fields in the view, one on each tab, and using jQuery to copy the value from one field to the other using the change event.

```
    $(function () {
        $('#job').find('#EffectiveDate').change(function () {
            var jobEffVal = $('#job').find('#EffectiveDate').val();
            $('#eval').find('#EffectiveDate').val(jobEffVal);
        });
        $('#eval').find('#EffectiveDate').change(function () {
            var evalEffVal = $('#eval').find('#EffectiveDate').val();
            $('#job').find('#EffectiveDate').val(evalEffVal);
        });
    });
```